# Упрощение запросов в бд

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Имеется таблица `users` и таблица `payments`

А так же страница с партнерской программой

Система группирует статистику пользователя по партнерской программе, т.е. зашел пользователь на страницу партнерской программы, система достает из таблицы его реферальный код и ищет пользователей в таблице `users`, которые активировали у себя этот код (способом перебора), как только найдены такие пользователи система с помощью того же перебора ищет записи каждого, кто использовал этот код в таблице `payments` и суммирует сумму платежей. Далее эта сумма передается изначальному пользователю и он получается статистику и соответственно свой уровень в реферальной программе.

Все это дело очень замедляет загрузку страницы ( из-за всех запросов страница загружается больше 5 секунд ). Нужно как то оптимизировать код, чтобы максимально ускорить загрузку страницы. Не представляю как изменить запросы, чтобы их упростить

Код:

```
$ref_users = User::where('invite', $user->ref_code)->get();

$all = 0;
foreach($ref_users as $ref){
    $all += Func::ref_deposited($ref->user_id);
}

$level = Func::getLevel($all);
```

Функция получения суммы всех платежей:

```
static function ref_deposited($user_id){
    $all = 0;
    $payments = PaySys::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('status', 1)->sum('amount');
    $payments2 = PaySys2::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'complete')->sum('amount');
    $deposits = TradeLog::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'success')->sum('amount');

    $all = $payments + $payments2 + $deposits;

    return round($all, 2);
}
```

Функция получения уровня:

```
static function getLevel($sum){

        $sum = Func::convertToUsd($sum);

        if($sum >= 0 && $sum < 500){
            $value['level'] = 1;
            $value['perc'] = 5;
            $value['refer'] = 0.30;
            $value['toNext'] = 500;
        }elseif($sum >= 500 && $sum < 2000){
            $value['level'] = 2;
            $value['perc'] = 6;
            $value['refer'] = 0.40;
            $value['toNext'] = 2000;
        }elseif($sum >= 2000 && $sum < 5000){
            $value['level'] = 3;
            $value['perc'] = 7;
            $value['refer'] = 0.45;
            $value['toNext'] = 5000;
        }elseif($sum >= 5000 && $sum < 7500){
            $value['level'] = 4;
            $value['perc'] = 8;
            $value['refer'] = 0.60;
            $value['toNext'] = 7500;
        }elseif($sum >= 7500 && $sum < 10000){
            $value['level'] = 5;
            $value['perc'] = 9;
            $value['refer'] = 0.65;
            $value['toNext'] = 10000;
        }elseif($sum >= 10000){
            $value['level'] = 6;
            $value['perc'] = 10;
            $value['refer'] = 0.70;
            $value['toNext'] = 99999;
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать справочник уникальных кодов и сумм по этому коду, навесив на него индексирование.
Если я правильно понимаю, в данной задаче нет необходимости определения пользователей, которые тоже использовали этот код, нужна лишь сумма. Так?
При таком раскладе пользователь не будет ожидать расчетов. А сами расчеты будут выполняться отдельно от сессии пользователя.

Или, возможно, есть доп.ограничения на временные интервалы?
Тогда можно использовать партицирование(partition) таблицы payments по дате, и последующее наложение фильтров на даты в запросе поиска. Это сузит границы поиска.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То есть вы предлагает создать новую таблицу столбцы (code, amount) и каждый раз, когда кто то пользуясь реферальным кодом пополняет баланс прибавлять сумму в строке кода?

Comment: Быть может я не правильно составил логику? и есть другой вариант быстро получить необходимые данные

Comment: Да, новую таблицу, да, каждый раз обновлять по триггеру, да, это дорогое удовольствие. Но так вы распараллелите процессы, и ваши клиенты не будут тратить время на ожидание расчетов.